# Migrating Access tables to SQL. Update queries do not work

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

The goal of the project is to migrate all Access tables to SQL, but continue the objects such as reports, queries, forms, and macros until we migrate over to the .NET framework.

It seems to work for the most part, but not some update queries.

This particular update query has the UPDATE statement followed by a join statement like this.

```
UPDATE (tblBid INNER JOIN Plan ON tblBid.Id = Plan.BidId)
SET ....
```

The error message reads, "Operation must be an updateable query"

I know in T-SQL, the table to be update follows UPDATE, not a join statement.  So how can I fix Access update queries  to make them compatible with SQL?  Obviously SQL does not like the Access update query.

EDIT:

I took Laurence's suggestion below and updated the query in SQL View (sorry.  I could not simplify it).

```
UPDATE [Plan Assemblies]
SET [Plan Assemblies].[Description] = ItemTemp.[Description]
FROM ([Bid Header] INNER JOIN [Plan] 
    ON [Bid Header].BidID = [Plan].BidID) INNER JOIN (ItemTemp INNER JOIN [Plan Assemblies] 
ON ItemTemp.ID = [Plan Assemblies].AssyID) ON [Plan].PlanID = [Plan Assemblies].PlanID 
WHERE [Bid Header].BidID = 1
```

The query executes in SQL.  In Access, when I try to save it in SQLView, I get the "syntax error missing operator in query expression ItemTemp.[Description].  So now Access is not happy with an expression that SQL is happy with.

Comment: The reality is that T-SQL and VBA are **not** identical.  It is very probable that you will need to develop 2 separate SQL statements; one for Access and one for SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only updating one of the tables, you can rewrite the query in T-SQL as

```
update
    b
set
    ...
from
    tblBid b
        inner join
    Plan p
        on b.Id = p BidID
```

If you are updating both, you could convert it to two update statements within a transaction.

You can also rewrite it in this way, which might be valid T-SQL and Jet SQL:

```
update
    tblBid
set
    ...
where
    exists (
        select
            'x'
        from
            Plan p
        where
            p.BidID = tblBid.Id
    );
```

Comment: So I have to SQL View to edit this thing?  Dear Gawd.

Comment: This might need to be a pass-through query too.

Comment: Please see my addendum.  I fixed it in accordance with your suggestion, and now Access isn't happy.  It works in SQL.

Comment: @user79284 see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303968 for info on how to create a Pass-Through query.

Comment: Closer, but not quite.  The update query reads a value from a form like this (WHERE ((([Bid Header].BidID)=[forms]![bid header]![bidid]))).  The error message says "Incorrect  syntax near '!'.(#102).  So it does not like that clause.  Is there a workaround?

Comment: So I am gathering that this is because SQL does not know anything about the forms and controls on the Access side, so it cannot resolve the parameters.  I hope there is a simple workaround to this.

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, T-SQL and Access have different UPDATE syntax. In T-SQL:

```
update Table
set Column = ...
from ...
```

In MS Access:

```
update Table
from ...
set Column = ...
```

Unless you generate the query dynamically in your application, there is no unified approach.